# Exce VBA: Highlight cells with two consecutive capital words

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to see if there is a macro to highlight a cell in which two consecutive words both start with a capital letter (i.e. Susan Smith, We went to the beach with Susan Smith, I can't believe This Wind)

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this solution.

Place the following in a standard code module and run it with the worksheet activated that you want to highlight the cells with consecutive capital words...

```
Sub ShowDblCapCells()
  Dim c&, i&, j&, t&, v, w
  Const COLOR = xlThemeColorAccent4

  v = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
      If Len(v(i, j)) Then
        For Each w In Split(v(i, j), " ")
          t = Asc(w)
          If t > 64 And t < 91 Then
            c = c + 1
            If c = 2 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ThemeColor = COLOR: Exit For
            End If
          Else
            c = 0
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

---

Update

Please try this version. I think it may solve your error...

```
Sub ShowDblCapCells()
  Dim c&, i&, j&, t$, v, w
  Const COLOR = xlThemeColorAccent4

  v = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
      If Len(v(i, j)) Then
        For Each w In Split(v(i, j), " ")
          t = Left(w, 1)
          If t = UCase(t) Then
            c = c + 1
            If c = 2 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ThemeColor = COLOR: Exit For
            End If
          Else
            c = 0
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

---

Update #2

After seeing your workbook, please use the following version...

```
Sub ShowDblCapCells()
  Dim c&, i&, j&, t&, v, w
  Const COLOR = xlThemeColorAccent4

  v = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
      If Len(v(i, j)) Then
        c = 0
        For Each w In Split(v(i, j), " ")
          t = Asc(w)
          If t > 64 And t < 91 Then
            c = c + 1
            If c = 2 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ThemeColor = COLOR: Exit For
            End If
          Else
            c = 0
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

---

**Update #3**

The following version works even when there are sub-strings with more than one space character in a rows...

```
Sub ShowDblCapCells()
  Dim c&, i&, j&, t&, v, w
  Const COLOR = xlThemeColorAccent4

  v = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
      If Len(v(i, j)) Then
        c = 0
        For Each w In Split(v(i, j), " ")
          If Len(w) Then
            t = Asc(w)
            If t > 64 And t < 91 Then
              c = c + 1
              If c = 2 Then
                  Cells(i, j).Interior.ThemeColor = COLOR: Exit For
              End If
            Else
              c = 0
            End If
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems to work in some workbooks, while others I receive a debug 5 error. When I debug, it references  t = Asc(w) 

Any idea on why that could be?

Comment: Are you in a country that use Unicode primarily... instead of ASCII?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer and let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: That seems to work. I created/inserted a form control button, which when I click on it the first time it highlights 2 cells in column A. When I click on the button a second time, it then highlights the appropriate cells that I'm hoping for. Is there a way to remove the highlighting that's happening in column A, as no information is there.

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't seem to work. It's still missing certain cells and data in columns, and it's also just highlighting cells that are all #'s. For instance, it picked up one cell that just had the following text: "Stated". An example of another cell where it had a number highlighted the value of "414601375"

Comment: Sent over! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi. The email never came through. I checked my spam folder as well. Can you send it again?

Comment: Sent over again.

Comment: I updated the answer to a version of the code that is working with your workbook.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is nearly perfect, except I do receive some file errors with a debug error related to t = Asc(w). Certain files they work perfectly...do you think if we entered in a line to clear formatting of the entire workbook that this would help?